# Run find on find

Tags: bash, find, xargs

I did a web seach for "linux run find on find" but it produced no relevant results. I want to build list of files by find and then run find again on that list.

After fixing some "silly" mistakes I guess coming from little experience with command line work, final command is:

```
find "path1" -size 0 -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 --max-args=1 --verbose find "path2" -exec ls -l {} \\\; -name
```

As `--verbose`, I see commands run as

```
find path -exec ls -l {} \; -name foundfilename
```

and output `missing argument to exec`.

If I run resulting command build by `xargs` directly (adding double quotes as for some reason xargs --verbose output misses, but apparently uses in practice as find does not have issues with path that includes spaces:

```
find "path" -exec ls -l {} \; -name foundfilename
```

and output looks like all files in `path`.

1. Why different result from xargs and direct `find` run?
2. Looks like `-exec` cannot precede `-name`, is it correct?
3. Finally to the point: How to properly run `find` on results on another `find`?

System: Linux Mint 19.2

**Added after comment to clarify 2nd question:**

If I run

```
find "path" -name foundfilename -exec ls -l {} \;
```

I got output of several files found and listed by `ls` as expected, that is to the 2nd question.

I did test setup of two files named `1` and `2` in `/media/ramdrive`.

```
marina@tpx:~$ find /media/ramdrive -exec ls {} \; -name 1
1  2
/media/ramdrive/2
/media/ramdrive/1
marina@tpx:~$ find /media/ramdrive -name 1 -exec ls {} \;
/media/ramdrive/1
```

Man on find:

> -exec command ;
> Execute  command;  true  if 0 status is returned.  All following
> arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until
> an  argument  consisting of `;' is encountered.  The string` {}'
> is replaced by the current file name being processed  everywhere
> it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments
> where it is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both  of  these
> constructions might need to be escaped (with a `') or quoted to
> protect them from expansion by the shell.  See the EXAMPLES sec‐
> tion for examples of the use of the -exec option.  The specified
> command is run once for each matched file.  The command is  exe‐
> cuted  in  the starting directory.   There are unavoidable secu‐
> rity problems surrounding use of the -exec  action;  you  should
> use the -execdir option instead.

I don't see why `-exec` cannot precede options for matching.

Actually I don't understand meaning of "everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it is alone".

ADDED TWO:
I though I found a solution by:

```
find "path1" -size 0 -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 --max-args=1 --verbose find "path2" -name | xargs ls -l
```

but default print from find does not quote results, so fails for path with spaces.  If there utility to add quotes?

Comment: @Theophrastus, path is real. The point is to find some file names by criteria (here zero size as an example) and than to find all such file names in some maybe other path. I now amending question to clarify.

Comment: @ Theophrastus , reproducible example for 2nd question added.

Comment: @Theophrastus, it is stated from the start: I want to build list of files by find and then run find again on that list. Would it be more helpful to state as "I want to find files by some complex criteria and then find files based list prepared on 1st step?"

Comment: @Theophrastus, for now it is zero size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why different result from `xargs` and direct `find` run?

When you *type* `find path -exec ls -l {} \; -name foundfilename` in a shell, the shell reads `\;` as "pass `;` to the command". If it was just `;` typed, it would be a command separator. The backslash gets "eaten" by the shell and changes its behavior regarding `;`.

When `xargs` says it *runs* `find path -exec ls -l {} \; -name foundfilename`, it actually passes `\;` to the command (i.e. to `find`), there is no shell to strip the backslash. So `\;` is wrong here: `-exec` expects `;` or `+`, it gets neither, therefore "missing argument to exec".

---

> Looks like `-exec` cannot precede `-name`, is it correct?

Incorrect. It can. Maybe it shouldn't, it depends on what you want to do. The different results from your two commands can be easily explained. The two commands are:

```
find /media/ramdrive -exec ls {} \; -name 1
find /media/ramdrive -name 1 -exec ls {} \;
```

Crucial facts:

- `-exec` is also a test. It succeeds iff the inner command returns `0`.
- Tests are joined by operators: `-o` (logical OR) or `-a` (logical AND). Where an operator is missing (like in your case), `-a` is assumed.
- With `-test1 -o -test2` or `-test1 -a -test2`, `-test1` is tested first. If the result is determined solely by `-test1` then `-test2` won't be performed. In particular this means `-test1 -a -test2` will run `test2` if and only if `-test1` succeeds (if it fails then `-test2` is not needed because we already know the result: failure).

If your overall test is `-exec ls {} \; -name 1` (i.e. `-exec ls {} \; -a -name 1`) then `-exec` is performed for every candidate. This already prints something to stdout. For each candidate `ls` succeeds, so the other test is performed; but it doesn't matter because the other test prints nothing and there are no further tests/actions (the default `-print` is suppressed by previous `-exec`).

If your overall test is `-name 1 -exec ls {} \;` (i.e. `-name 1 -a -exec ls {} \;`) then `-name` is performed for every candidate. The test prints nothing, but the result of it decides if `-exec` is performed. So `ls` runs iff `-name` succeeds, it prints something iff `-name` succeeds.

---

> How to properly run `find` on results on another `find`?

It's possible to run `find` from within `-exec` of another `find`. E.g. this finds all symlinks in directories named `lib`:

```
find / -type d -name lib -exec find {} -type l \;
```

You can get results from `/lib/`, `/var/lib/`, `/usr/lib/` etc.

There are few problems:

- This runs one inner `find` per one result from the outer `find`. The situation is different if you want to use all the results from one `find` at once, i.e. with a *single* other `find`.
- If the inner `find` also needs to run `-exec` then there is no straightforward way to pass `{}`, `;` (typed as `\;`) or `+` to it, because these will be interpreted by the outer `find`. One solution is to use `xargs` (and [you did](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560760/108618)) which in general requires non-POSIX options to make it not fail for names containing newlines. Another solution is to spawn a shell between the two `find`s (like in [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560767/108618) which appeared when I was composing mine, I won't repeat its solution).

---

> I don't understand meaning of "everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it is alone".

[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) requires `find` to expand *alone* `{}`. For arguments like `{}.txt` or `foo{}bar` "it is implementation-defined whether `find` replaces those two characters or uses the string without change". Your version of `find` will replace `{}` in arguments like `{}.txt` or `foo{}bar` and the manual explicitly states this.

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
find path1 -size 0 -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    find path2 -name "${file##%/}" -exec ls -ld \{\} +
  done' sh {} +
```

(assuming none of the names of the empty files  contain wildcard characters or backslashes as `-name` treats its argument as a *wildcard pattern*).

Since your `find` is the one from GNU, you could also replace `-exec ls -ld \{\} +` with `-ls` (neither `-printf` nor `-ls` are standard but while `-printf` is GNU-specific, `-ls` is much more portable though the output format varies slightly between implementations).

More generally, you don't want to pipe the output of `find` into `xargs` unless you use the GNU-style `xargs -r0` and get `find` to output NUL-delimited records (with `-print0` or your `-printf '%f\0'` for instance). In most of the cases it's better to use `-exec ... {} +` than piping to `xargs`. More generally, [Kamil's answer](/a/560768) very nicely explains the problems in your approach, I won't repeat it here.

Here, you could use the `zsh` shell instead:

```
for file (path1/**/*(NDL0)) ls -ld path2/**/$file:t(DN)
```

(which doesn't have the wildcard character issue)

Answer (score 1):

Following hint by @muru to use `-I` in `xargs`, the working command (assuming GNU implementations of `find` and `xargs`) is:

```
find "path1" -size 0 -printf "%f\0" |
  xargs -r0 -I mystr find "path2" -name mystr -exec ls -ld {} +
```

(that assumes the names of the empty files don't contain wildcard characters as `-name` interprets its argument as a *wildcard pattern*)

Comment: @Stéphane, thanx for the edit/ why `+` at the end of exec here is better than `\;`?

Comment: `-exec cmd {} +` passes as many filenames as possible to each invocation of `cmd` while `-exec cmd {} ';'` runs one `cmd` invocation with one filename argument for each file. Here `ls` can take more than one file name as argument (note that it will also sort the list it receives) and running fewer invocations will make it a lot more efficient.