# Utility to add quotes to argument

Tags: bash, quoting

I have an issue which can be solved with utility to add quotes to argument and output to standard. I did a web seach for "linux utility to add quotes to argument" and found nothing relevant. Is there amy? (will need to pair it with xargs)

P.S. original issue (see at the end for quick understanding):
[Run find on find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560739/run-find-on-find)

Comment: Why do you need quoting for that? Just continue to use `-print0` and `-0` as you were already doing

Comment: @muru, looks like `find` (at least GNU one I have) does not work as would be expected if action expression is before criteria expressions, and I need to pass criteria (name) by xargs at the end.

Comment: No, you don't. Use xargs with `-i`/`-I`

Comment: @muru, yes it works this way. Would you like to type a quick answer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560739/run-find-on-find and I except it? Should I delete this one after?

Comment: You can post an answer showing the command you finally used. Yes, this question doesn't add much, you can delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how that could help with your other problem, but if indeed you need a command that prints its arguments separated by a space character and the whole thing surrounded with `"` and terminated by a newline character, you could do it with `awk`:

```
awk -- '
  BEGIN{
    printf "\""
    for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) printf "%s", (i == 1 ? "" : " ") ARGV[i]
    print "\""
  }' arg1 "arg 2" 'arg 3' 'arg "4"'
```

prints:

```
"arg1 arg 2 arg 3 arg "4""
```

Answer (score 0):

My original issue got proper solution suggested by @muru, however maybe of any use `C` utility for quoting I now wrote (my system had `quote` command but it quoted only 1st argument, ignoring the rest), as usual use `gcc quoteit.c -o quoteit && chmod +x quoteit` to build provided code in quoteit.c in current folder:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{ 
    if (argc ==2 && (!strcmp(argv[1],"-h") || !strcmp(argv[1],"--help")))
    {
        printf("The program surrounds set of arguments with double quotes\n");
        printf("Example: quoteit 12 23 outputs \"12 23\"\n");
        return 0;
    } 
    //printf("%d\n", argc); 

    printf("\""); 
    for (int i=1; i< argc; i++) 
    {
        printf("%s", argv[i]); 
        if (u<args-1) printf(" ");
    } 
    printf("\"");
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple Bash script could do that:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "\"$*\""
```

Already `$*` generate the full list of arguments. `echo` simply sourrounds them with escaped quotes.

```
myquote.sh hi, 'how do' you "do?"
"hi, how do you do?"
```

Now, **related** to the intended use of this 'quoter' script to put quotes around filenames obtained with `find` in its `exec` clause, it is not necessary, because you can add the quotes directly to the curly braces argument, like in this example, to be correctly received by the `grep` command:

```
find /etc -exec grep -Hi "{}" \;
```

or, in case of piping to `xargs`, using the `-print0` clause to mark the filenames with a NULL delimiter for the `xargs` command next in the pipe.

Comment: The quotes around `{}` in your `find` command do nothing. The argument replaced in `{}` is not split by the shell in any case.

Comment: Confirmed by testing, but the man page of `find` (exec clause section) explicitly states: "[semicolon or curly braces]...might  need  to  be escaped (with a '\') or quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell", so there is no guarantee of portability.

Comment: In the context of this question, which is tagged with [tag:bash], the `{}` does not need quoting. Likewise, in any other `sh`-like shell, `{}` does not need quoting. If you're using `tcsh`, or some other non-standard shell, then `{}` may need quoting.